# Android: How to go back to previous screen after playing YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube

My app plays a specific YouTube video when a button is clicked.
After watching the video I want the YouTube video player to close and the app to go back to the previous screen instead of displaying more suggested videos.
Here is the code I have, how do I do that?

```
package com.newapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class Level_1_Training extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        if (!wasRestored) {

        player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get onVideoEnded() callback.

Youtube API link here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener#onVideoEnded()
You can add your logic in implemented method.

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);   
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onAdStarted() { }

            @Override 
            public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() { }

            @Override 
            public void onVideoEnded() {
    //your logic ,if the previous activity to be called , 
    // you can perform backpress() or intent to call other activity. 
    // also dont forget to remove player in the 
    // onStop() method of the youtube activity.

     }  
            @Override 
            public void onVideoStarted() { }
        });
        }
    }
```

Useful references

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/youtube-android-player-api-example

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What logic would you add to destroy the youtube player and go back to the Menu activity? I haven't done Java in a long time, do you mind editing my code?

Comment: I put the whole code to make it simple, I still don't understand how to use it, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I have edited the answer with onInitializationSuccess implementation. please follow that lead.

Comment: Now I understand it, you made me build a new statechangelistener. I did put finish() in the onVideoEnded() and it worked, now when the video stops playing it goes back to the menu screen. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you are satisfied and problem is resolved, you can always accept the answer for future references. Thanks !!